# Why is this code not working? Output is not being printed

Tags: c++14

When I compiled in devc++ compiler, output is not printed. Is there any logical error? This program should accept a number from the user, print the lowest palindrome greater than the given number.

It is a problem from  SPOJ PALIN

## include

using namespace std;

int main()
{

```
int t;

cin>>t;
cout<<endl;

while(t--)
{long long int i;
long long int k;
int flag=1;
long long int n;
int a[10000000];
    cin>>n;
    n++;
    start:
    i=0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        a[i]=n%10;
    i++;
    n=n/10;}
    i--;
    k=i;
    for(int j=0;j<=k;j++)
{   
    if(a[i]!=a[j])
    {flag=0;break;}
    else
    i--;
}
if(flag==1)
cout<<n<<endl;
else
{n++;goto start;}

}
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the flag variable. if(a[i]==a[j]) then the flag will remain uninitialized and may create problems while cheking the if condition unless the default value will be 0 for it.(I am not sure that it would be). Also I can see that the value of flag will never turn 1 according to your code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace::std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    cout<<endl;
    while(t--)
    {
        long int i, k, n;  int a[1000];  int flag = 1, duplicaten;
        cin>>n;
        n++;

        start:
        //cout<<"inside start : n = "<<n<<"\n";
        flag=1; i=0;
        duplicaten=n;
        while(n!=0)
        {
            a[i]=n%10;
            i++;
            n=n/10;
        }
        n=duplicaten;
        i--;
        k=i;
        //cout<<"number of digits of n = "<<i+1<<"\n";
        for(int j=0;j<=k;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]!=a[j])
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
            else
            i--;
        }
        //cout<<"flag = "<<flag<<endl;
        if(flag==1)
        {
            //cout<<"FOUND!!\n";
            cout<<n<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            n++;
            //cout<<"NOT found\n";
            goto start;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can change the size of your data types yourself and atleast vote up this answer.
[< Output before using duplicaten : link to image >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQVV5.jpg)

Comment: also indent your code properly and try to make it as easy as possible for others to comprehend your program. This is a way easy program and I can see that your style may create problems at a later stage when your programs turn large.

Comment: Sir,even after initializing it to 1,the code doesn't work.In online judge it shows Time limit exceeded and in devc++ compiler it doesn't run.

Comment: Think of it this way. Suppose that after some iterations your program encountered a number that is palindrome. So what do you do now. Your program will never set flag to 1 and will keep on iterating and hence the condition flag==1 will be true only in case there are two consecutive palindrome numbers and the user has made the input of the smaller of the two. You need another flag variable to set if the number you have checked is palindrome or not. The thing you are doing inside the for loop is not giving you any outcome. As for the time complexity you can do many things over here like:

Comment: 1. inner for loop can go upto only half the number of digits. 2. You can break out of the for loop once you know for sure that the number is not palindrome. You need not check any further digits. 3. and the most IMPORTANT of the one is that the online judge softwares are not that reliable. I have had countless experience on hackerrank when my code was running fine with the right output in some milliseconds while it was showing a timeout of 2 seconds. So don't get discouraged however this is not the case for you. I am not giving you the working code as I think you are a novice programmer

Comment: and try to solve these petty problems on your own. If you can't seem to find your problem just place multiple couts outputting the value of all the needed variables after major operations  inside the iteration and check where the value is not desired at each step.

Comment: sir,I have initialized flag inside while loop,first a number is checked,if it is not a palindrome,in the else condition it is incremented by 1 and the process starts again,if it is found to be a palindrome it is printed,this process happens t times.And yes I am a novice programmer.

Comment: didn't you read the shit I just told you?? YOU ARE NOT PRINTING IF ITS A PALINDROME. where is the condition that checks if its a palindrome?? you are just checking the digits from the front and the back, whether they are equal or not. How will the computer know if its a palindrome? there has to be a condition that if all the digits from the front and back are equal then the number IS palindrome and set the flag to 1 over there. Otherwise once the flag is set to 0, its never set to 1 again and hence you have created an infinite loop

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the working code and see how I debugged your error using the couts. I have also added images of what I was getting without the duplicaten. This is the way to debug and asking for help here over these type of probelems won't help.